# Convert VarHandle to java.lang.reflect.Field

Tags: java, reflection, java-9

Is there any way to convert from a `VarHandle` to a `java.lang.reflect.Field`?  With a (getter/setter) `MethodHandle`, one can use `MethodHandles.reflectAs(Field.class, handle)` to go from `MethodHandle` to `Field` or `lookup.unreflect{Getter|Setter}(field)` to go from `Field` to `MethodHandle`.  Similarly, one can use `lookup.unreflectVarHandle(field)` to go from `Field` to `VarHandle`, but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent way to go from `VarHandle` to `Field`.

Answer (score 3):

Such a function does indeed seem to be missing.

But starting with JDK 12, you can emulate it via the constant API:

```java
Optional<Field> o = varHandle.describeConstable().map(d -> {
    String mName = d.bootstrapMethod().methodName();
    if(mName.equals("staticFieldVarHandle") || mName.equals("fieldVarHandle")) try {
        return ((Class<?>)((ClassDesc)d.bootstrapArgsList().get(0))
            .resolveConstantDesc(MethodHandles.lookup()))
            .getDeclaredField(d.constantName());
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {}
    return null;
});
```

This provides the `Field` when the `VarHandle` is describing an accessible field.

Comment: Good trick, but falls a bit short since the field needs to be accessible, whereas `MethodHandles.reflectAs` works even if the field is inaccessible.  Interestingly, the way Java 12 implements the `describeConstable` method is not to add the `MethodName` to the `VarHandle` anywhere, but to add `VarHandles.getFieldFromReceiverAndOffset` and `VarHandles.getStaticFieldFromBaseAndOffset` which return the `Field` and could trivially be used to implement something like `VarHandle.reflect`.

Comment: Well, usually, it’s not easy to construct a `VarHandle` for the inaccessible field in the first place. Not that the accessibility restriction only applies to the owner class, the field is then looked up via an ordinary `getDeclaredField` which can see inaccessible fields. In principle, you could even extract the class name and do a lookup yourself. But yes, it would still not be the same as a `reflectAs` that works independently from the caller’s context.

Comment: I'm thinking about the case where the VarHandle is created from a caller that can see the field, and then passed to a utility class that can't (for example, something like AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater).  If the utility class needs the reflected field handle (for type assertions or such), there's no easy way to get it.  An alternative, is to instead pass the MethodHandle.Lookup and the name of the field, and let the utility class lookup the field (reflectAs on the getter handle) and the varhandle itself.

Comment: I think we agree that this is a missing feature…